# Array initialization for class scope in c++11

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I come from Java and Ruby so I have a hard time coding simple stuff in c++, c++ being harder to tame...

I want to initialize an array in the class constructor with predefined values that can be accessed by all methods in the class. Yeah, basic stuff.

In other words, I want to do something like this:

**Box.h**

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
     SomeClass(int something);
     SomeMethod();
     DoSomething(int thing);
protected:
     int _something;
     int[] arr;
};
```

**Box.cpp**

```
SomeClass::SomeClass(int something) : something(_something)
{
    arr ={16,2,45,65,45};
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        arr[i] = arr[i] * _something;
}

SomeClass::SomeMethod(){
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
       DoSomething(arr[i]);
}

SomeClass::DoSomething(int thing){
    //whatever
}
```

How?

Comment: Do you want the array size to be fixed at compile time?

Comment: yeah, but all its values have to be initialized in the constructor

Comment: You should probably indicate whether you want a C++11 or C++03 solution.  Unfortunately, there is no way to do exactly what you are indicating in C++03.  You'd have to create a temporary array in your constructor as you have and then use a for or other algorithm (e.g., fill, generate).  Unfortunately, I don't know of a C++ 11 way to do exactly that either, but there are some additional options and container types that allow it to be done differently.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the title to specify which C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <initializer_list>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

class foo
{
    public:
    foo() : values({{16,2,45,65,45}})
    {
        // I left the below commented out in case you want to research more and use other kinds of types for doing it.
        //std::initializer_list<int> list = {16,2,45,65,45};
        //std::copy(std::begin(list), std::end(list), std::begin(values));
    }
    void print()
    {
        std::for_each(std::begin(values), std::end(values), 
           [](int v) { std::cout << v << ' '; });
    }

    private:
    static const int SIZE = 5;
    std::array<int, 5> values;
};

int main()
{
   foo fooInstance;
   fooInstance.print();
   return 0;
}
```

The above is the best that I could do in a short period of time.  I tested with the following compiler.  You could use that as a starting point and see if you can learn other ways of doing it.  Algorithms such as generate can also be used with lamda expressions in order to generate a controlled set of values (as opposed to a hard coded list as in our examples).
http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php

Answer (score 1):

You have options for initializing array data members, and two types or array you can use:

Using a C-style array,

```
struct Foo
{
  int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};   // initialization at point of declaration
};

struct Bar
{
  int a[5];
  Bar() : a{1,2,3,4,5} {} // initialization in constructor initialization list
};
```

Or using an `std::array`:

```
struct Foo
{
  std::array<int,5> a = {{1,2,3,4,5}};   // initialization at point of declaration
};

struct Bar
{
  std::array<int,5> a;
  Bar() : a{{1,2,3,4,5}} {} // initialization in constructor initialization list
};
```

Comment: Using C-style array for initialization in constructor initialization list, I get an error..: cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays

Comment: @FelixD. You probably are missing the relevant C++11 support.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++11, there is support for [uniform initialization](http://mbevin.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/uniform-initialization/) which allows you to assign brace-enclosed lists of values in more contexts than the special case in C.